# Pictures exceed block height in Next.js

Tags: next.js

I have a block that should be 440px in height, the pictures and other blocks should fit into this height, but the pictures go beyond the height of the block.

**Component:**

```
import React from "react";
import style from "./TourGalery.module.scss";
import Image from "next/image";

interface Props {
  images?: React.ReactNode[];
}

const TourGalery = (props: Props) => {
  return (
    <div className={style["galery"]}>
      <div className={style["main-image"]}>
        <Image src={props.images && props.images[0]} alt="Picture of the author" className={style["galery-image"]} />
      </div>
      <div className={style["other-images"]}>
        {props.images?.slice(1, 3).map((img, index) => {
          return <Image key={index} src={img} alt="Picture of the author" className={style["galery-image"]} />;
        })}
        {props.images && props.images?.length > 3 ? (
          <div className={style["image-count"]}>
            <h1>+{props.images?.length - 3}</h1>
          </div>
        ) : (
          ""
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TourGalery;
```

**Styles:**

```
.galery-image {
  border-radius: 16px;
  width: 100%;
}

.galery {
  height: 440px;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  .main-image {
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 16px;
    margin-right: 8px;
  }
  .other-images {
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    .image-count {
      padding: 62px 0px;
      text-align: center;
      border: 1px solid #d6dde0;
      border-radius: 12px;
      h1 {
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #989ea0;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**The component should look like this:**
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7y3Sz.jpg)

**But my component at this stage looks like this:**
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLaHS.png)

I tried to set fixed values, but then the picture is distorted, but I would like it to adapt to the block size. I also tried experimenting with the layout parameter, but it didn’t lead to anything.

Comment: for `.main-image`, changing from `height: 100%` to `max-height: 100%` would make it fit to the parent container.

Comment: @HarshTuwar It didn't work

Comment: @Salivan You can use the `fill` prop on your image, than wrap it with a div that is displayed relatively. This will cause the image to match the div dimensions. You can also set `object-fit: cover` inside your image css so it does not distort.